# How can I add a different legend for different quantiles in the same graph in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
           ggplotRegression <- function (fit) {

            require(ggplot2)

           ggplot(fit$model, aes_string(x = names(fit$model)[2], y = 
          names(fit$model)[1])) + 
            geom_point() +
            stat_smooth(method = "lm", col = "red") +
            labs(title = paste("Adj R2 = ",signif(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 
              5),
                   "Intercept =",signif(fit$coef[[1]],5 ),
                   " Slope =",signif(fit$coef[[2]], 5),
                   " P =",signif(summary(fit)$coef[2,4], 5)))
```

}

```
               taus <-c(0.05  , 0.25, 0.50 , 0.75, 0.90 , 0.95)

                m <- ggplotRegression( lm(formula = BMI ~   height_in_m 
                  +weight_in_kg+ Highest_Education_level + 
                   wealth_index + age_in_year_groups, data = dat_new))

             m+geom_quantile(quantiles=taus, lwd=1.5 , col="green4", 
             fill=taus)
```

[image]

Now I want to add specific colours for each quantiles and also add spcific legend for each quantiles .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ggplot statistics let you use the results of the calculation enclosed in `..`, for example with `geom_density` you can use `..count..` in the `aes`.

With `geom_quantile` you can use `..quantile..`

```
df <- data_frame(x = rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_quantile(aes(colour = as.factor(..quantile..)))
```

The trick is to find out what these variables are called. Geoms that need to calculate statistics, such as `geom_quantile` and `geom_density`, have an associated `ggproto` object such as `StatQuantile` and `StatDensity` which has the code for the calculations in an element called `compute_group`.

The last command of `StatQuantile$compute_group` is

```
    plyr::ldply(quantiles, quant_pred, data = data, method = method, 
    formula = formula, weight = weight, grid = grid, method.args = method.args)
```

The function here, `quant_pred` - which you can see with `ggplot2:::quant_pred`, returns a list. The components of this list, including `quantile`, can be used in the `aes`.