# How can I add a geom_quantile legend to this customized facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I recently [received great help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60655019/why-does-strip-text-color-from-facet-wrap-not-correspond-to-element-text-color) from SO in producing this customized `facet_wrap`-plot shown below.

**Question:** how can I add the dotted linetype used in `geom_quantile(linetype=2)` as legend with the text "50th percentile"?

I have sought solutions in [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44383464/how-can-i-add-a-different-legend-for-different-quantiles-in-the-same-graph-in-gg) on SO, but my question has not been answered.

My current plot looks like this

[image]

Produced with the following code

```
cols = c("#E1B930", "#2C77BF","#E38072","#6DBCC3")
ggplot(p, aes(x=n.fjernet,y=os.neck)) + geom_point(aes(color=uiccc),shape=20, size=5,alpha=0.7) + 

  geom_quantile(quantiles = 0.5,col="black", size=1,linetype=2, show.legend = F) + facet_wrap(.~factor(uiccc)) +

  scale_fill_manual(values=cols) + 

  scale_colour_manual(values=cols)  +

  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,50, by=10), name="Lymph nodal yield") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Time to death (months)") +

  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(color = "transparent"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(t=10)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(r=10)),
        legend.position="none",
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,3,1,1), "lines")) +
        coord_cartesian(clip = "off",ylim = c(0,175)) +
        geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(uiccc), 
        aes(label = factor(uiccc), color = uiccc), y = 190, x = 30, hjust = 0.5, fontface = "bold",cex=5)
```

I would like the plot to have a legend that indicates the "50th percentile" as demonstrated by the `linetype=2` in `geom_quantile()`, exclusively, which looks like this (manually added in photoshop):

[image]

First: I have removed `theme(legend.position="none")`

Second: I have added `show.legend=TRUE` in `geom_quantile`

Third: I have added `show.legend=FALSE` in `geom_point`

Unfortunately, these edits does not produce the requested legend:

[image]

How can I proceed?

My data `p`

```
p <- structure(list(n.fjernet = c(18L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 
16L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 13L, 33L, 16L, 6L, 9L, 23L, 9L, 8L, 13L, 5L, 
30L, 25L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 38L, 5L, 7L, 15L, 4L, 6L, 15L, 
9L, 8L, 7L, 4L, 6L, 10L, 8L, 4L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 14L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 20L, 3L, 26L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 10L, 15L, 
29L, 7L, 6L, 11L, 17L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 9L, 20L, 34L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 
11L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 8L, 5L, 18L, 7L, 9L, 13L, 18L, 19L, 
14L, 46L, 23L, 11L, 6L, 18L, 20L, 4L, 2L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 11L, 13L, 
13L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 12L, 11L, 16L, 6L, 13L, 8L, 17L, 5L, 8L, 22L, 
19L, 3L, 15L, 14L, 7L, 18L, 9L, 10L, 18L, 24L, 11L, 15L, 7L, 
6L, 4L, 24L, 23L, 8L, 20L, 9L, 22L, 11L, 2L, 24L, 15L, 5L, 8L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 6L, 16L, 7L, 9L, 16L, 11L, 33L, 27L, 16L, 
57L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 12L, 5L, 9L, 49L, 11L, 28L, 19L, 
13L, 23L, 11L, 12L, 10L, 4L, 14L, 6L, 12L, 32L, 13L, 12L, 4L, 
11L, 17L, 10L, 5L, 15L, 21L, 19L, 11L, 31L, 9L, 20L, 11L, 16L, 
12L, 6L, 16L, 27L, 30L, 18L, 18L, 10L, 7L, 23L, 16L, 15L, 4L, 
12L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 9L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 
35L, 12L, 5L, 19L, 27L, 34L, 10L, 16L, 18L, 6L, 22L), os.neck = c(11.5, 
74.38, 17.02, 7.89, 96.03, 40.48, 17.74, 14.65, 62.46, 12.55, 
9.92, 26.05, 45.47, 17.38, 39.72, 51.45, 8.61, 76.98, 67.09, 
94.79, 72.15, 93.93, 17.05, 12.48, 91.6, 15.87, 11.04, 67.22, 
67.02, 8.94, 6.6, 5.09, 10.68, 17.15, 0.07, 5.19, 40.77, 0.2, 
170.88, 5.55, 1.61, 38.28, 10.58, 32.99, 110.98, 103.69, 122.32, 
14.78, 42.74, 4.04, 8.28, 84.96, 11.7, 49.97, 120.48, 52.6, 71.26, 
16.3, 100.14, 55.03, 6.51, 89.89, 51.71, 24.97, 55.66, 21.91, 
81.48, 30.92, 1.58, 7.52, 30.75, 3.45, 19.22, 5.42, 17.68, 45.54, 
76.22, 125.34, 83.62, 30.82, 90.32, 1.84, 19.98, 20.53, 32.59, 
54.77, 2.3, 106.84, 22.28, 45.18, 4.47, 39.66, 32.3, 16.23, 3.88, 
2.23, 0.23, 18.73, 0.79, 28.75, 79.54, 14.46, 15.15, 54.97, 48.59, 
34.83, 58.42, 35.29, 45.73, 57.53, 63.11, 65.05, 29.54, 77.21, 
63.48, 83.35, 34.3, 64.49, 29.54, 62.69, 21.62, 49.35, 99.02, 
15.8, 41.89, 12.98, 13.8, 43.6, 57.23, 31.38, 70.74, 39.46, 20.76, 
67.22, 127.15, 74.12, 1.97, 7.39, 25.17, 28.22, 14, 36.53, 20.83, 
19.55, 40.77, 27.76, 45.31, 34.46, 35.55, 26.94, 9.43, 10.51, 
6.8, 8.18, 8.02, 14.29, 6.11, 13.8, 4.9, 4.04, 14.82, 11.66, 
73.07, 92.91, 99.98, 10.64, 10.05, 95.8, 7.23, 12.81, 43.99, 
13.9, 10.25, 16.36, 18.2, 18.76, 12.32, 8.64, 11.79, 112.04, 
70.97, 31.28, 28.85, 21.49, 19.94, 22.14, 29.44, 67.62, 11.01, 
45.24, 110.72, 20.24, 14.06, 12.88, 31.51, 8.08, 13.08, 21.45, 
24.28, 21.98, 32.89, 23.26, 15.41, 15.41, 13.8, 40.12, 8.02, 
15.77, 49.81, 18.17, 24.21, 47.08, 6.6, 37.16, 13.01, 8.38, 14.36, 
18.27, 17.28, 73.76, 68.21, 22.83, 2.66, 69.06, 17.05, 8.61, 
23.33, 13.34, 12.65, 8.77, 128.92, 16.1, 4.99, 11.73, 22.97, 
40.12, 20.37, 2.04, 45.73), uiccc = structure(c(4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("UICC Stage I", 
"UICC Stage II", "UICC Stage III", "UICC Stage IV"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-239L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to specify a "fake" `color` title in the `aes` of `geom_quantile`.

Then, you can remove legend for points and labels by adding `show.legend = FALSE` into their respective `geom` and manipulate `breaks` in `scale_color_manual` to show only the color attribute for your `50th percentile` category. Finally, manipulating various parameters for `legend` in `theme` will get you to what you desired.

Altogether, you can have a code like this (PS: `scale_fill_manual` is useless in your current example):

```r
ggplot(p, aes(x=n.fjernet,y=os.neck)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=uiccc),shape=20, size=5,alpha=0.7, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_quantile(aes(colour = "50th percentile"), quantiles = 0.5, size=1,linetype=2) + 
  facet_wrap(.~factor(uiccc)) +
  #scale_fill_manual(values=cols) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=cols, breaks = c("50th percentile"), name = "")  +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(0,50, by=10), name="Lymph nodal yield") +
  scale_y_continuous(name="Time to death (months)") +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text = element_text(color = "transparent"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(t=10)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 14, face="bold", margin=ggplot2::margin(r=10)),
        legend.position="top",
        legend.text=element_text(size=rel(2)),
        legend.key.size = unit(2, "cm"),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,3,1,1), "lines")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off",ylim = c(0,175)) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(uiccc), 
            aes(label = factor(uiccc), color = uiccc), y = 190, x = 30, hjust = 0.5, fontface = "bold",cex=5, show.legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: again, thank you. It did exactly what I requested. Being completely new, could you recommend any literature webpages, etc., on how to develop dplyr and ggplot skills?

Comment: You're welcome. As general documentation for ggplot and dplyr, I would suggest those link:  https://r4ds.had.co.nz/ and http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/. Also, you can find more useful links here: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ggplot2/info. Also, take a look on official documentation of each function in order to found some good examples.