# How to manually specify legend text/color in this ggplot composed of several different geoms?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, dplyr

Please, find my data sample `ndd` below.

**Question:** how can I add a customized legend to this ggplot composed of different `geoms`?

I have tried approaching as described in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60669243/how-can-i-add-a-geom-quantile-legend-to-this-customized-facet-wrap), but wihtout luck.

I have produced this plot:

[image]

However, no matter what I try, I cannot manually change the legend. I have tried `show.legend=FALSE` and adding "an extra" fake color in `geom_area`, which did not work or, at least, I did it wrong.

I would like the legend to look like this:

[image]

The color order correspond to `c("#E1B930", "#2C77BF","#E38072","#6DBCC3")`.

Obviously, I tried specifying that in `cols`. However, it then changes the color order in `geom_area` to start with `"#E1B930" (the orange)`. The one `geom_point` with color placed at `geom_point(x=0,y=18.3)` should have `"#E1B930" (the orange)`, as  currently in the picture/code, whereas `geom_area` comes in this color order: `c("#2C77BF","#E38072","#6DBCC3")`.

To me, the tricky part is that the four groups in the legend should have the color order as described: `c("#E1B930", "#2C77BF","#E38072","#6DBCC3")`

**Please**, feel free to improve or optimize my script. I am completely new to `tidyverse` and I am eager to learn.

Thank you in advance.

```
cols = c("#2C77BF", "#E38072","#6DBCC3", "grey40")

as.data.frame(approx(ndd$lnd, ndd$y, xout=c(ndd$lnd, 8.001, 15.00001,100))) %>% 
  set_names(c("lnd", "y")) %>% 
  mutate(xcut = cut(lnd, c(0,8,15,100), include.lowest=TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(lnd, y))  + 

  geom_area(aes(fill=xcut, color=c("f")), alpha=0.2) +

  geom_line(size=6,color="white") +
  geom_line(size=2, alpha=.9) +

  geom_segment(aes(x=0,y=0,xend=8,yend=0),color="#2C77BF", size=1.1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=8,y=0,xend=15,yend=0),color="#E38072", size=1.1) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=15,y=0,xend=35,yend=0),color="#6DBCC3", size=1.1) +

  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = ndd$y[1], xend = 0, yend = -0.2), lty="solid", size=1.2, color="#E1B930") +

  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = ndd$y[1]), size=5, shape=20, col="#E1B930", alpha=0.5) +

  geom_point(aes(x=8,y=0.337),color="black",shape=20, size=5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=15,y=0.475),color="black",shape=20, size=5) +

  annotate("text", x = 7.8, y = 0.35, label = "15%-point increase",hjust=1, 
           cex=3.28, vjust=0.5, fontface=2, col="darkgrey") +
  annotate("text", x = 14.8, y = 0.493, label = "15%-point increase",hjust=1, 
           cex=3.28, vjust=0.5, fontface=2, col="darkgrey") +

  scale_fill_manual(values=cols, breaks = c("f"), name="") +
  scale_colour_manual(values=cols, breaks = c("f"), name="") +

  scale_x_continuous(name="LND", breaks=seq(0,100,by=5), 
                     label=c(paste0("LND: 0% \nas baseline"), paste0(seq(5,100,5),"%")), limits=c(0,35)) +

  scale_y_continuous(name = "5-yrs risk of death", breaks = seq(0,1,by=.1),
                     label=paste0(seq(0,100,10),"%"))  +

  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1)) +

  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=11, color=c("#E1B930",rep("grey20",15))),
                plot.title = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 13,face="bold",hjust = 0.5))
```

My data

```
ndd <- structure(list(y = c(0.183, 0.185, 0.188, 0.191, 0.193, 0.196, 
                          0.199, 0.202, 0.205, 0.208, 0.211, 0.214, 0.217, 0.22, 0.223, 
                          0.226, 0.229, 0.232, 0.235, 0.237, 0.24, 0.243, 0.245, 0.248, 
                          0.25, 0.253, 0.255, 0.257, 0.259, 0.261, 0.263, 0.265, 0.267, 
                          0.269, 0.27, 0.272, 0.273, 0.275, 0.276, 0.278, 0.279, 0.28, 
                          0.281, 0.283, 0.284, 0.285, 0.286, 0.287, 0.288, 0.289, 0.29, 
                          0.292, 0.293, 0.294, 0.295, 0.296, 0.297, 0.299, 0.3, 0.301, 
                          0.302, 0.304, 0.305, 0.307, 0.308, 0.31, 0.311, 0.313, 0.315, 
                          0.316, 0.318, 0.32, 0.322, 0.323, 0.325, 0.327, 0.329, 0.331, 
                          0.333, 0.335, 0.337, 0.339, 0.341, 0.343, 0.345, 0.347, 0.349, 
                          0.351, 0.353, 0.355, 0.358, 0.36, 0.362, 0.364, 0.366, 0.368, 
                          0.371, 0.373, 0.375, 0.377, 0.379, 0.382, 0.384, 0.386, 0.388, 
                          0.39, 0.393, 0.395, 0.397, 0.399, 0.401, 0.403, 0.405, 0.407, 
                          0.41, 0.412, 0.414, 0.416, 0.418, 0.42, 0.422, 0.424, 0.426, 
                          0.428, 0.43, 0.432, 0.434, 0.436, 0.438, 0.439, 0.441, 0.443, 
                          0.445, 0.447, 0.449, 0.451, 0.452, 0.454, 0.456, 0.458, 0.46, 
                          0.461, 0.463, 0.465, 0.467, 0.468, 0.47, 0.472, 0.473, 0.475, 
                          0.477, 0.478, 0.48, 0.481, 0.483, 0.485, 0.486, 0.488, 0.489, 
                          0.491, 0.492, 0.494, 0.495, 0.497, 0.498, 0.5, 0.501, 0.503, 
                          0.504, 0.505, 0.507, 0.508, 0.51, 0.511, 0.512, 0.514, 0.515, 
                          0.516, 0.517, 0.519, 0.52, 0.521, 0.522, 0.524, 0.525, 0.526, 
                          0.527, 0.528, 0.53, 0.531, 0.532, 0.533, 0.534, 0.535, 0.536, 
                          0.537, 0.539, 0.54, 0.541, 0.542, 0.543, 0.544, 0.545, 0.546, 
                          0.547, 0.548, 0.549, 0.55, 0.551, 0.551, 0.552, 0.553, 0.554, 
                          0.555, 0.556, 0.557, 0.558, 0.559, 0.559, 0.56, 0.561, 0.562, 
                          0.563, 0.563, 0.564, 0.565, 0.566, 0.566, 0.567, 0.568, 0.569, 
                          0.569, 0.57, 0.571, 0.572, 0.572, 0.573, 0.574, 0.574, 0.575, 
                          0.576, 0.576, 0.577, 0.577, 0.578, 0.579, 0.579, 0.58, 0.58, 
                          0.581, 0.582, 0.582, 0.583, 0.583, 0.584, 0.584, 0.585, 0.585, 
                          0.586, 0.586, 0.587, 0.587, 0.588, 0.588, 0.589, 0.589, 0.59, 
                          0.59, 0.591, 0.591, 0.592, 0.592, 0.593, 0.593, 0.593, 0.594, 
                          0.594, 0.595, 0.595, 0.595, 0.596, 0.596, 0.597, 0.597, 0.597, 
                          0.598, 0.598, 0.599, 0.599, 0.599, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.601, 0.601, 
                          0.602, 0.602, 0.602, 0.603, 0.603, 0.603), lnd = c(0, 0.1, 0.2, 
                                                                             0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 
                                                                             1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 2.8, 
                                                                             2.9, 3, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9, 4, 4.1, 
                                                                             4.2, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7, 4.8, 4.9, 5, 5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4, 
                                                                             5.5, 5.6, 5.7, 5.8, 5.9, 6, 6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4, 6.5, 6.6, 6.7, 
                                                                             6.8, 6.9, 7, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, 7.6, 7.7, 7.8, 7.9, 8, 
                                                                             8.1, 8.2, 8.3, 8.4, 8.5, 8.6, 8.7, 8.8, 8.9, 9, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3, 
                                                                             9.4, 9.5, 9.6, 9.7, 9.8, 9.9, 10, 10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, 10.5, 
                                                                             10.6, 10.7, 10.8, 10.9, 11, 11.1, 11.2, 11.3, 11.4, 11.5, 11.6, 
                                                                             11.7, 11.8, 11.9, 12, 12.1, 12.2, 12.3, 12.4, 12.5, 12.6, 12.7, 
                                                                             12.8, 12.9, 13, 13.1, 13.2, 13.3, 13.4, 13.5, 13.6, 13.7, 13.8, 
                                                                             13.9, 14, 14.1, 14.2, 14.3, 14.4, 14.5, 14.6, 14.7, 14.8, 14.9, 
                                                                             15, 15.1, 15.2, 15.3, 15.4, 15.5, 15.6, 15.7, 15.8, 15.9, 16, 
                                                                             16.1, 16.2, 16.3, 16.4, 16.5, 16.6, 16.7, 16.8, 16.9, 17, 17.1, 
                                                                             17.2, 17.3, 17.4, 17.5, 17.6, 17.7, 17.8, 17.9, 18, 18.1, 18.2, 
                                                                             18.3, 18.4, 18.5, 18.6, 18.7, 18.8, 18.9, 19, 19.1, 19.2, 19.3, 
                                                                             19.4, 19.5, 19.6, 19.7, 19.8, 19.9, 20, 20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 
                                                                             20.5, 20.6, 20.7, 20.8, 20.9, 21, 21.1, 21.2, 21.3, 21.4, 21.5, 
                                                                             21.6, 21.7, 21.8, 21.9, 22, 22.1, 22.2, 22.3, 22.4, 22.5, 22.6, 
                                                                             22.7, 22.8, 22.9, 23, 23.1, 23.2, 23.3, 23.4, 23.5, 23.6, 23.7, 
                                                                             23.8, 23.9, 24, 24.1, 24.2, 24.3, 24.4, 24.5, 24.6, 24.7, 24.8, 
                                                                             24.9, 25, 25.1, 25.2, 25.3, 25.4, 25.5, 25.6, 25.7, 25.8, 25.9, 
                                                                             26, 26.1, 26.2, 26.3, 26.4, 26.5, 26.6, 26.7, 26.8, 26.9, 27, 
                                                                             27.1, 27.2, 27.3, 27.4, 27.5, 27.6, 27.7, 27.8, 27.9, 28, 28.1, 
                                                                             28.2, 28.3, 28.4, 28.5, 28.6, 28.7, 28.8, 28.9, 29, 29.1, 29.2, 
                                                                             29.3, 29.4, 29.5, 29.6, 29.7, 29.8, 29.9, 30)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                           -301L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: try this, `scale_fill_manual(values=cols, label = c("group 1","group 2","group 3"), name = "legends")` , it is difficult to put group 1 in the legend though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a possible solution to create your legend of interest.

Basically, I add a group to your `approx` and `cut` functions in order to generate 4 groups instead of 3. Then, using `scale_fill_manual`, it is much easier to get the desired legend.

In order to avoid the repetition of `geom_segment`, I generate a dataframe that will hold coordinates for each segment based on each groups.

```r
cols_group =  c("#E1B930","#2C77BF", "#E38072","#6DBCC3")

DF <- as.data.frame(approx(ndd$lnd, ndd$y, xout=c(ndd$lnd, 0.1,8.001, 15.00001,100)))  %>% 
  set_names(c("lnd", "y")) %>% slice(.,1:nrow(ndd)) %>% 
  mutate(xcut = cut(lnd, c(0,0.1,8,15,100), include.lowest=TRUE))

segment_df <- DF %>% group_by(xcut) %>%
  summarise(xmin = min(lnd, na.rm = TRUE),
            xmax = max(lnd, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Then, I integrate these two dataframe into your ggplot code as follow:

```r
ggplot(DF,aes(lnd, y))  + 
  geom_area(aes(fill=xcut), alpha=0.2) +
  geom_line(size=6,color="white") +
  geom_line(size=2, alpha=.9) +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "", values = cols_group, labels = paste("Group",1:4))+
  geom_segment(data = segment_df,
               aes(x = xmin, xend = xmax, y = 0, yend = 0, color = xcut), size = 1.1, show.legend = FALSE)+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, y = ndd$y[1], xend = 0, yend = 0), lty="solid", size=1.2, color="#E1B930") +  
  scale_color_manual(values = cols_group)+
  geom_point(aes(x = 0, y = ndd$y[1]), size=5, shape=20, col="#E1B930", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=8,y=0.337),color="black",shape=20, size=5) +
  geom_point(aes(x=15,y=0.475),color="black",shape=20, size=5) +
  annotate("text", x = 7.8, y = 0.35, label = "15%-point increase",hjust=1, 
           cex=3.28, vjust=0.5, fontface=2, col="darkgrey") +
  annotate("text", x = 14.8, y = 0.493, label = "15%-point increase",hjust=1, 
           cex=3.28, vjust=0.5, fontface=2, col="darkgrey") +
  scale_x_continuous(name="LND", breaks=seq(0,100,by=5), 
                     label=c(paste0("LND: 0% \nas baseline"), paste0(seq(5,100,5),"%")), limits=c(0,max(ndd$lnd))) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "5-yrs risk of death", breaks = seq(0,1,by=.1),
                     label=paste0(seq(0,100,10),"%"))  +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,1)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(colour="grey20",size=11, color=c("#E1B930",rep("grey20",15))),
        plot.title = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 13,face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = cols_group, color = cols_group, lwd = 1)))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**EDIT: Adding color borer for each box in legends**

As asked by OP, you can add border color to each box of the legend by using `guides` function and following arguments:

```r
guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = cols_group, color = cols_group, lwd = 1)))
```

`lwd` control the size of the border while `color` and `fill` control the border color and the filling of each box.

Comment: Hi @dc37. It definitely answers my question. Brilliant! As always, thank you very much. One thing, the `green #6DBCC3` `geom_segment` does not print when copy-pasting your code. Any idea why?

Comment: You're welcome. I think it is because I set x limits to 30 (based on the example dataset provided). But I guess that your original data (based on your graph goes up to 35). I edited my answer. Let me know if it is working now.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. You're right. This is a `dput()`, the `ndd$lnd` goes up to `100` in the original data. Therefore, in `scale_x_continuous( ... , limits = c(0, max(ndd$lnd))` makes the x-axis goes all the way up to `100` which unfortunately looks a bit off graphically. I manually changed back to `limits = c(0,30)`, however, that removed  the green `geom_segment` again.

Comment: I just changed from `100` to `30` in `approx()` and `xcut`, which solved it! Your help is much appreciated! Until next time :)

Comment: Great that your figure it out ;) An another option is to pass x limits into `coord_cartesian` like that it won't "remove" parts of your graph not fitting to the plot area.

Comment: Sorry for the additional question. Would it be possible to change the `shape` of the four `square-shapes` in the current legend? I would like to keep the four squares, but with a border corresponding to `cols_group` with `alpha=1` and a fill corresponding to `cols_group` with `alpha=0.2` (as the squares have in the current example). Let me know if it is a too big "comment question".

Comment: Only in the legend ?

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly. Take a look at the last line ;)